# How can I query several words in indexed fields in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo, text-search, multi-query

When I want to execute a indexed text search i use the following command:

```
text_results = db.command('text', 'foo', search=query)
```

I am now wondering how I can query several words. I tried already to set the query to `query = ['word1', 'word2']` but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Using the the search string `"word1 word2"` searches for the term `word1` OR the term `word2`:

```
text_results = db.command('text', 'foo', search='word1 word2')
```

Also, here's a quote from **[docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases)**:

> If the search string includes phrases, the search performs an AND with
>   any other terms in the search string; e.g. search for "\"twinkle
>   twinkle\" little star" searches for "twinkle twinkle" and ("little" or
>   "star").

So to search where the field contains `"word1"` AND `"word2"`, go for

```
text_results = db.command('text', 'foo', search="\"word1\" \"word2\"")
```

Comment: I am looking for a query which will return a result where the field contains "word1" and "word2"

Comment: so the query looks printed like this: "\word1\ word2\"?